# Activeadmin: can't name a model 'Action'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We had a problem in ActiveAdmin with a model named 'Action'. We couldn't save an attribute. On a hunch, my colleague solved the problem by renaming the model 'Activity'.

Is there a list somewhere of models names who are incompatible with ActiveAdmin? Is that possible that a term is restricted, but nothing in the system tells you so?

Comment: what is the actually error that you are getting.. attach Stacktrace or error log.. for further clarity. I don't think Action is reserved in ActiveAdmin, it it's highly improbable that such ActiveAdmin would restrict such thing unless its rails specific. 'action' is rails specific but "Action" isn't.. so yeah.. please attach some error log/Stacktrace for further elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here a list of reserved words [here](http://www.rubyplus.net/2011/07/reserved-words-in-rails.html). As you can see, `action` is listed as potentially problematic, so you'd rather not use it and rename your model.

Comment: `Action` is *potentially* different from `action`

Comment: Sure. But considering that in addition of that, it is the prefix of many modules in rails (ActionRecord, ActionView, ActionCable...), I would avoid it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of reserved words in ruby and rails [link](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words)